# Ability to add user-data to Facebook post and use it while quering thru FQL or Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-stream-story

Is there a way to add user-data (a number or a string) and use it while querying posts from the stream of that page ?

Essentially I am trying to make posts with certain attributes on a Facebook page thru an App and would like to query the stream (newsfeed) on that page using FQL or Graph API and just select the specific posts based on the attributes added to the posts.

```
SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE **user_data** ='tag-specified-with-post' app_id='APP_ID'.
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use FQL to get posts from your app. [This query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20app_id,%20post_id,%20actor_id,%20target_id,%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20filter_key%20=%27owner%27%20AND%20is_hidden%20=%200%20AND%20app_id=%272305272732%27%0A) will get posts made in the account of the user by the Photos app:

```
SELECT app_id, post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key ='owner' AND is_hidden = 0 AND app_id='YOUR_APP_ID'
```

Replace that `app_id` with yours. And replace `filter_key` with 'others' to get other people's posts that the user can view.

Comment: Thanks Tommy for your feedback. I realize that I did not specify the fact that I am attempting to select certain posts made by the App (not all). So this would require me to add this attribute (or user-data) to the post and then use that to do the select. So the above query would need to look like : SELECT app_id, post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE user_data ='earlier-posted-tag' AND is_hidden = 0 AND app_id='APP_ID'. (I have edited the question to higlight this)